# Understanding the JaCoCo coverage XML report

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco

I have managed to create a JaCoCo XML coverage report. In the report I get:

```
<class
name="PATH"
 sourcefilename="DeleteUtility.java">
  <method name="&lt;init&gt;"
  desc="(Lcom/commons/treenode/PathNode;)V"
   line="20">
    <counter type="INSTRUCTION" missed="17" covered="0" />

    <counter type="LINE" missed="6" covered="0" />

    <counter type="COMPLEXITY" missed="1" covered="0" />

    <counter type="METHOD" missed="1" covered="0" />
  </method>
...
```

I have a few questions about the format:

1. Sometimes the method name is `&lt;init&gt;"` or `"&lt;clinit&gt;"`. I guess it's `<init>` and `<clinit>`. What does those methods mean?
2. What does `desc` mean?
3. What does `COMPLEXITY` mean?
4. Is `INSTRUCTION` the amount of keywords in the method?

Answer (score 2):

`Instruction` smallest unit JaCoCo counts are single Java byte code instructions. Instruction coverage provides information about the amount of code that has been executed or missed.

`Complexity` calculates cyclomatic complexity for each non-abstract method and summarizes complexity for classes, packages, and groups.

`Method` Each non-abstract method contains at least one instruction. A method is considered as executed when at least one instruction has been executed

`Line` For all class files that have been compiled with debug information, coverage information for individual lines can be calculated

`Branch` The total number of branches (if and switch statements) in a method that can be executed or missed.

see the documentation in Jacoco https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html

Comment: Thank you. What about other questions? I could not find information about them in the docs

Answer (score 0):

`<init>` is the contructor the a class DeleteUtility

`<clinit>` is the code coverage of static variables (e.g. `static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingExample.class.getName())`. In the HTML report it is stated as `static{...}`

`desc` contains the parameters types and return-type of the method. In your example the only parameter would be PathNode and the return type would be void (V).

There are some special cases for `desc`:

- Classes: starts with a leading `L` (e.g. `Ljava/lang/String`)
- Array as parameter: starts with a leading `[` (e.g. `[Ljava/lang/String`)
- primitive types: are only represented with one special char

  - byte: B
  - short: S
  - int: I
  - long: J
  - float: F
  - double: D
  - boolean: Z
  - char: C
  - void: V

A method like the following:

```
public int foo(int i, byte[] b, String s, ABC a, long l) {..}
```

would have the following `desc:`

```
desc="(I[BLjava/lang/String;Lorg/foo/ABC;J)I"
```